# Difference between paired t-test and lmm

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, heteroscedasticity, assumptions

I am trying to understand whether an experimental variable that we will call "candy_position" has an effect on the reaction times (called here "rt") of people during a task. All of the participants have been exposed to both levels of the candy_position variable multiple times, every time recording the rt.

Data structure (I am using R):

```
head(my_data)
   rt candy_position subject
1 842        invalid       1
2 533          valid       1
3 447        invalid       1
4 777          valid       1
5 568        invalid       1
6 464        invalid       1
summary(my_data) 
       rt         candy_position     subject     
 Min.   : 233.0   invalid:10695   29     :  609  
 1st Qu.: 523.0   valid  : 5454   14     :  598  
 Median : 599.0                   3      :  597  
 Mean   : 669.3                   10     :  593  
 3rd Qu.: 721.0                   26     :  593  
 Max.   :2380.0                   18     :  586  
                                  (Other):12573  
str(my_data)
'data.frame':   16149 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ rt            : num  842 533 447 777 568 464 490 641 484 462 ...
 $ candy_position: Factor w/ 2 levels "invalid","valid": 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ subject       : Factor w/ 30 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

At first, I use my_data and fit the following model:

```
fit_disag <- lmer(rt ~ candy_position + (1 | subject), data = my_data,  REML = F) # model on "disaggregated" data
```

Summary:

```
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: rt ~ candy_position + (1 | subject)
   Data: my_data

      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 205401.2  205432.0 -102696.6  205393.2     16145 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.8898 -0.6375 -0.1568  0.4822  6.2386 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 subject  (Intercept) 46959    216.7   
 Residual             19292    138.9   
Number of obs: 16149, groups:  subject, 30

Fixed effects:
                     Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)           673.663     39.587    30.023   17.02  < 2e-16 ***
candy_positionvalid    -6.826      2.314 16119.060   -2.95  0.00318 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
cndy_pstnvl -0.020
```

Confidence intervals:

```
confint.merMod(fit_disag, method = "boot")
Computing profile confidence intervals ...
                       2.5 %     97.5 %
.sig01              156.1083 269.097075
.sigma              137.4191 140.355508
(Intercept)         593.3297 752.228079
candy_positionvalid -11.6192  -2.378901
```

Then, I run the corresponding Paired t-test, expecting similar results. To do so, I take the mean of reaction times by subject and candy_position:

```
# using dplyr   
my_data_ag = my_data %>%
      group_by(candy_position,subject) %>%
      summarise(rt = mean(rt))
```

t.test:

```
    t.test(
my_data_ag$rt[my_data_ag$candy_position=="invalid"],
my_data_ag$rt[my_data_ag$candy_position=="valid"],
paired = T
) # t-test on "aggregated" data

    Paired t-test

data:  my_data_ag$rt[my_data_ag$candy_position=="invalid"] and my_data_ag$rt[my_data_ag$candy_position=="valid"]
t = 0.67302, df = 29, p-value = 0.5063
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -10.69199  21.18005
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
               5.244033
```

The results are clearly different from each other. The t-value calculated with the model is 2.95 and the t-value calculated with the t-test is 0.67. The confidence intervals are different as well. However, if I run the same model with the aggregated data, I have the same results as the t-test.

```
fit_ag <- lmer(rt ~ candy_position + (1 | subject), data = my_data_ag,  REML = F)
```

Summary:

```
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: rt ~ candy_position + (1 | subject)
   Data: my_data_aov

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   725.6    734.0   -358.8    717.6       56 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.32151 -0.50097 -0.03063  0.49278  2.31316 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 subject  (Intercept) 47210.2  217.28  
 Residual               880.3   29.67  
Number of obs: 60, groups:  subject, 30

Fixed effects:
                    Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          673.715     40.038  30.554  16.827   <2e-16 ***
candy_positionvalid   -5.244      7.661  30.000  -0.685    0.499    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
cndy_pstnvl -0.096
```

Confidence intervals:

```
confint.merMod(fit_ag, method = "boot")
Computing bootstrap confidence intervals ...
                        2.5 %    97.5 %
.sig01              158.35544 268.33066
.sigma               21.71941  37.56582
(Intercept)         595.52501 750.26305
candy_positionvalid -20.53977  10.16653
```

If I look at the t-values they look really different (0.68 | 2.95), confidence intervals as well are different, but one is included in the other (-20.53977  10.16653 | -11.6192  -2.378901), and this makes me wonder if it could be a matter of less uncertainty because I am modeling a larger dataset.
Still, I don't understand why there should be so much difference between the two models. Am I doing something wrong with the model on disaggregated data?

Residuals for the model on aggregated data:
[image]

Residuals of the model on disaggregated data:
[image]

I am asking this question mainly to learn more about linear mixed models and how to properly use them to get meaningful insights on data. Thank you in advance for any suggestion/reference/answer.

Comment: Why would you assume that t-test gives same results as LMM?

Comment: Try 1) `my_data <- my_data %>% group_by(subject) %>% mutate(prop_valid = mean(candy_position))`, then 2) `m1a <- lmer(rt ~ candy_position + prop_valid + (1|subject), my_data)`. The coefficient and test of significance on prop_valid should match or be very similar as your paired t-test.

Comment: @ErikRuzek 'my_data <- my_data %>% group_by(subject) %>% mutate(prop_valid = mean(candy_position))' this throws an error since candy_position is not logica nor numeric. If you meant 'my_data_prova <- my_data %>% group_by(subject) %>% mutate(prop_valid = mean(candy_position == "valid"))', I tried it and it is not the case. But thank you, you are giving me insights. Could you explain better your point? Are you pointing at the fact that every subject has a different proportion of "valid" and "invalid" trials? It is true, but the difference is not that drammatic (prop_valid, mean=0.33 sd=0.022).